# Prevent integrated terminal from opening automatically

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

Whenever I open a PowerShell script in VS Code, the integrated terminal opens. How can we prevent the integrated terminal from opening automatically. I have searched the settings for "terminal" and have found nothing associated with auto-start.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

VSCode will remember your last session.

So, if you close the terminal and exit VSCode, the next time you open, the terminal will not be displayed.

You can set your VSCode profile to not display (close the terminal on load).

As for User Settings:

This is not the first time this has been asked for.

https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/580

> ***powershell.startAutomatically***: When set to true (default), causes the
> language service to start automatically the first time a PowerShell
> file is opened. You could then use the "Restart PowerShell Session"
> command to kick off the language service on demand. •
>
> ***powershell.showIntegratedConsoleOnStartup:*** When set to true (default),
> causes the integrated console window to be shown automatically when
> the language service starts. If false, the language service starts but
> the console window isn't shown until the user runs script code (or
> runs the Show Integrated Console command)

***Update as per the OP side discussion with me***

What I just tested.
In your custom user settings, either set the:

"powershell.enableProfileLoading": false

or if you have that setting this way:

"powershell.enableProfileLoading": true

Add this setting:
"powershell.integratedConsole.showOnStartup": false,

Comment: "So, if you close the terminal and exit VSCode, the next time you open, the terminal will not be displayed." That is not happening in version `1.24.0 6a6e02cef0f2122ee1469765b704faf5d0e0d859
x64`.

Comment: `showIntegratedConsoleOnStartup` setting does not exist in the user settings list.

Comment: I was just updated to v1.24.1 last night, and it works. Just did it to revalidate.

Comment: I will try the v.12.1 version and see what happens.

Comment: With v1.2.1 the following happens: `> code someFile.psm1`, code opens the file and shows the integrated terminal, close the integrated terminal, close code, `> code someFile.psm1`, code opens the file and shows the integrated terminal. So, it is not remembering my last session.

Comment: Ah! I am not trying to run a file on load. I am just starting VSC from  the default Windows shortcut. By the way you are starting this, I take it you are on OSX/*NIX. Btw, just tested again on Win and disable the 'User Setting', "powershell.startAutomatically": false and fired up code from cmd.exe with a file and the terminal did not open, but the file did. I default to my terminal being open, so, this is something I've not used this way.

Comment: I'm on Windows.

Comment: I just found this user setting: `"powershell.integratedConsole.showOnStartup": false`. It appears to work.

Comment: Roger that. So, as noted, I just did it and no terminal on load.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173237/discussion-between-shaun-luttin-and-postanote).

Comment: For some reason I could not find a working solution. I then found [this workaround on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/39137#issuecomment-414127477) which uses JS. It's not the best solution but it works until this is sorted out.

Answer (score 9):

#### What Worked

```
"powershell.integratedConsole.showOnStartup": false
```

If the setting isn't there yet, then simply add it.

#### What Almost Worked

Setting `"powershell.startAutomatically": false` also kills the entire PowerShell extension.

Relying on VSCode to remember the last session's setup works inconsistently; for instance, it does not work when loading a file directly from a terminal with `$ code someFile.psm1`.

Comment: This setting does not exist for me in Windows settings.json

Comment: @jakobarsement It's a text file. If the setting isn't there, then add the setting.

Comment: Unknown configuration settings - 2022

Answer (score 6):

I believe the setting is:

`"terminal.integrated.enablePersistentSessions": false`

regardless of Powershell or other types of terminals. This should be self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

My VSCode v1.65.2
File->Preferences->Settings
In the Search settings input field:

- Type the word-> terminal

Under Extensions:

- Click-> Remote-SSH
- Uncheck-> Always reveal the SSH login Terminal.

Close all VSCode windows and restart VSCode.
Open the remote SSH location and the integrated terminal should no longer open automatically.