# How to run specific command on vscode close

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I would like to run a specific command when closing my vscode instance.

How can I achieve that?

### Objective

run the `Terminals: Kill` from the [Terminals Manager](https://github.com/fabiospampinato/vscode-terminals) library when closing the vscode windows to be able to clear every terminal & then avoid having useless terminal opened by vs-code.

*[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50880084/prevent-integrated-terminal-from-opening-automatically) could have done the trick, but I'm not using powershell*

Answer (score 0):

There is a native VSCode setting that revives all workspace processes.

In your settings menu search "**Enable Persistent Sessions**" and disable it. Now after closing a window the already opened terminals, will *not* reopen.

Comment: Thx, but I wish to "run a specific command on vsCode close". So I dont think your answer help me for that matter

Answer (score -1):

Well, my solution uses **AutoHotKey** to run two commands in order to kill all terminals and close VSCode:

```autohotkey
#if WinActive("ahk_exe code.exe")
  !F4::
    Send, ^!+{t}
    Sleep, 1000
    Send, !{f4}
Return
```

Using just the [Send](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Send.htm) and [Sleep](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Sleep.htm) commands.

`Send, ^!+{t}` This is a custom VSCode keybiding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> for `Terminals: Kill All Terminals`

`Sleep, 1000` Then wait a bit for Terminals to finish it's command

`Send, !{f4}` And here is the default Windows exit window command <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>

Hope it helps!